# c# Data Type That Represents Ranges Of Integers

Tags: c#, range

I want to know if there is an already made data type for ranges. It'll must have capability more than just representing a range of numbers, but also to have a value to a range and to be able to intersect ranges, to explain better I'll show what I'm expecting with C# code as if there was this kind of data type.

```
        RangeCollection rc = new RangeCollection();
        //rc.Add(new Range(from, to, value));
        rc.Add(new Range(1, 4, 1));
        rc.Add(new Range(3, 6, 2));
        Console.WriteLine(rc[1]); // output is: 1
        Console.WriteLine(rc[4]); //output is: [1,2]
```

I know I can do it myself, but I want to know if there is something already existing which is similar or partially like this.
Thanks!

Comment: See this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19028/Building-a-Generic-Range-class

Comment: Hi Neolisk, i've seen the question, and it does not meet all of my needs (it doesn't have a value nor can it intersect two ranges). I'm checking out the code project like no, so thanks!

Comment: Regarding the above SO answer - should be easy to extend from that point, like 1 line per each intersect, union etc. Or just use the CodeProject one - that is fairly rich already.